# Check all elements of a list (Drools Expert)

Tags: java, rules, drools, decision-tree, rule-engine

I'm trying to write rules in Drools Expert. In the `when` part of the rule, I check some properties of an `Application` object. This object contains a List and I would like to check if a bunch of rules apply to all objects of SomeOtherType in this list. The rule should fire only when the constraints are valid for ALL objects in that list.

```
rule "Application eligible"
    when
        app : Application(
               some constrains
               & write some constraints for all objects in app.getList() (a method
               that returns a List<SomeOtherType> object)
        )
    then 
        // application is eligible
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert all your `SomeOtherType` instances into the working memory too if you haven't already.
Then try something like this if you want to check that all SomeOtherType's have the color RED:

```
rule "Application eligible"
when
    $app : Application()
    forall( $x : SomeOtherType( application == $app ) 
            SomeOtherType( this == $x, color == RED ) )
then 
    // application is eligible
end
```

Comment: Is it possible without installing all the `SomeOtherType` instances into working memory? For example using `forall` together with `from`?

Comment: Yes, but `from` starts backwards chaining instead of forward chaining IIRC, which can have performance consequences (see manual). There are also other interesting keywords that might work, such as `collect` IIRC (also see manual).

Comment: What does "application" mean in "SomeOtherType( application == $app ) "? Maybe you mean "Application"? @Smet

Answer (score 3):

I also found another kind of hack-y way to do this if you want to get around having to insert your object into working memory using collect as Geoffry suggested:

```
rule "Person has all brothers"
  when
    $person : Person(siblings != null, siblings.size > 0) 
    List(size == siblings.size) from collect (Person(sex != null, sex == "m") from $person.siblings)
  then
    #Person has all brothers
  end
```

Comment: Why is it a hack-y way ?