# forall always evaluates to be true [Drools]

Tags: java, drools, rules, rule-engine

I have a class Application, within which there is a list of instances of CallPhones.

```
class Application() {
      List<CallPhones> callPhonesList;
      ...
}

class CallPhones() {
      Integer callTimes;
      ...
}
```

I want to fire the rule when `callTimes` of all instances larger than 10. Here is the rule:

```
rule "Application eligible"
    when
        app : Application()
        forall(CallPhones(callTimes > 10))
    then 
        // application is eligible
end
```

Strangely, **the rule always fires**, even when there's an instance with `callTimes` being 5. I also tried answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106500/check-all-elements-of-a-list-drools-expert), but got no help. Any ideas?

Comment: `from app.callPhoneList` is missing even `:` is missing

Comment: Could you give a complete example? @piyushj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
rule "Application eligible"
    when
        app : Application()
        forall($temp:CallPhones(callUserTimes > 10) from app.callPhoneList)
    then 
        // application is eligible
end
```