# forall always evaluates to be true [Drools 6.3 final]

Tags: drools

I am a newbie for Drools. Would like to ask a question about the conditional element forall. Ｉhave some classes and the following UML diagram shows the relationships among these objects:　
[UML diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE13h.jpg)

One order has one customer and has a list of orderlines.
Each orderline is linked to one item. Frankly speaking, it is a sample code of one book about Drools.

Ｉwant to fire the below rule when the customer of order is SILVER category and all items in the order are in high range  ( with high cost), in order to setup the discount of the order. Here is the rule:

```
rule "Silver Customers + High Range Order - 10% Discount -1"
when

    $o: Order( $lines : orderLines.size >= 2, $customer: customer, discount == null )
    $c: Customer( category == Category.SILVER, this == $customer )
    forall( OrderLine( this memberOf $lines,  $item : item)
            Item(this == $item, category == Item.Category.HIGH_RANGE)
    )
then
    $o.setDiscount(new Discount(10.0));
    update($o); 
end
```

The problem is the rule always fires, even when I tried to insert one order with 5 items in low range.

In the debug info i found that the category of the first item was LOW_RANGE but the rule was still fired:

```
==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[[ Silver Customers +  High Range Order - 10% Discount active=false ] [ null
[fact 0:1:1561745898:141057847:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.devguide.eshop.model.Customer:Customer [id = null, age=null, email=null, name=null, category = SILVER]]
[fact 0:12:1971991758:-345298280:12:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.devguide.eshop.model.Order:Order [ id = null, customer=Customer [id = null, age=null, email=null, name=null, category = SILVER], date=Fri Oct 21 11:11:38 CST 2016, lines=[OrderLine [item=Item{id=1, name=A, cost=80.0, salePrice=800.0, category=LOW_RANGE}, quantity=1], OrderLine [item=Item{id=1, name=B, cost=800.0, salePrice=850.0, category=HIGH_RANGE}, quantity=2], OrderLine [item=Item{id=1, name=C, cost=800.0, salePrice=850.0, category=HIGH_RANGE}, quantity=3], OrderLine [item=Item{id=1, name=D, cost=800.0, salePrice=850.0, category=HIGH_RANGE}, quantity=4], OrderLine [item=Item{id=1, name=E, cost=800.0, salePrice=850.0, category=HIGH_RANGE}, quantity=5]], state=PENDING, discount=null]] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
-------------------
rule triggered:Silver Customers + High Range Order - 10% Discount
==>[AfterActivationFiredEvent: getActivation()=[[ Silver Customers + High Range Order - 10% Discount active=false ] [ null
[fact 0:1:1561745898:141057847:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.devguide.eshop.model.Customer:Customer [id = null, age=null, email=null, name=null, category = SILVER]]
[fact 0:12:1971991758:-345298280:18:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.devguide.eshop.model.Order:Order [ id = null, customer=Customer [id = null, age=null, email=null, name=null, category = SILVER], date=Fri Oct 21 11:11:38 CST 2016, lines=[OrderLine [item=Item{id=1, name=A, cost=80.0, salePrice=800.0, category=LOW_RANGE}, quantity=1], OrderLine [item=Item{id=1, name=B, cost=800.0, salePrice=850.0, category=HIGH_RANGE}, quantity=2], OrderLine [item=Item{id=1, name=C, cost=800.0, salePrice=850.0, category=HIGH_RANGE}, quantity=3], OrderLine [item=Item{id=1, name=D, cost=800.0, salePrice=850.0, category=HIGH_RANGE}, quantity=4], OrderLine [item=Item{id=1, name=E, cost=800.0, salePrice=850.0, category=HIGH_RANGE}, quantity=5]], state=PENDING, discount=10.0 % ]] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
```

I have read the answers of the question: [forall always evaluates to be true [Drools]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606319/forall-always-evaluates-to-be-true-drools) . I tried the solution, but i got another wrong result, the below rule never fires even i used an order with all high range items:

```
rule "Silver Customers + High Range Order - 10% Discount"
when

    $o: Order( $lines : orderLines.size >= 2, discount == null )
    $c: Customer( category == Category.SILVER ) from $o.customer
    forall( OrderLine() from $o.orderLines
            OrderLine( item.category == Item.Category.HIGH_RANGE)
    )
then
    $o.setDiscount(new Discount(10.0));
    update($o);
end
```

The unittest code is below:

```
@Test
public void highRangeOrderDiscountTest() {
    KieSession kSession = createDefaultSession();

    Order o = ModelFactory.getOrderWithFiveHighRangeItems();

    kSession.insert(o.getCustomer());
    kSession.insert(o.getOrderLines().get(0));
    kSession.insert(o.getOrderLines().get(1));
    kSession.insert(o.getOrderLines().get(2));
    kSession.insert(o.getOrderLines().get(3));
    kSession.insert(o.getOrderLines().get(4));
    kSession.insert(o.getOrderLines().get(0).getItem());
    kSession.insert(o.getOrderLines().get(1).getItem());
    kSession.insert(o.getOrderLines().get(2).getItem());
    kSession.insert(o.getOrderLines().get(3).getItem());
    kSession.insert(o.getOrderLines().get(4).getItem());
    kSession.insert(o);

    int fired = kSession.fireAllRules();

    // We have 5 Items that are categorized -> 5 rules were fired
    // We have 1 Customer that needs to be categorized -> 1 rule fired
    // We have just one order with all HIGH RAnge items -> 1 rule fired
    // One Coupon is created for the SILVER Customer -> 1 rule fired
    assertThat(8, is(fired));
    assertThat(o.getCustomer().getCategory(), is(Customer.Category.SILVER));
    assertThat(o.getDiscount(), not(nullValue()));
    assertThat(o.getDiscount().getPercentage(), is(10.0));


}
}
```

Could you tell me the cause or tell me the correct usage of forall ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This establishes the set of OrderLine-s and then ascertains that all pertain to a high range item. (Note: untested)

```
rule "Silver Customers + High Range Order - 10% Discount"
when
    $c: Customer( category == Category.SILVER )
    $o: Order( $lines : orderLines.size >= 2, customer == $c,
               discount == null )
    forall( OrderLine( $item : item) from $lines
            Item(this == $item, category == Item.Category.HIGH_RANGE))
then
    modify( $o ){ setDiscount(new Discount(10.0)) }
end
```

All Customer and Item objects must be inserted as facts; it would be reasonable to do this for OrderLine-s as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution still fired the rule for low range items.

Answer (score 0):

there is a mistake in the book :

$o: Order( $lines : orderLines.size >= 2, customer == $c, discount == null )

must be

$o: Order( $lines : orderLines, orderLines.size >= 2, customer == $c, discount == null )